# How to redirect nginx request to different path

Tags: nginx, webserver, phabricator

Here is my ***nginx.conf*** which serves any request coming to `example.com` with `/srv/phabricator/phabricator/webroot/index.php`. I want to change the functionality such that if a request comes in to `example.com/test` then `/home/phragile/public/index.php` is served.

```
daemon off;
error_log stderr info;
worker_processes  1;
pid        /run/nginx.pid;

events {
    worker_connections  4096;
    use epoll;
}

http {
    include       /etc/nginx/mime.types;
    default_type  application/octet-stream;
    sendfile        on;
    keepalive_timeout  65;
    gzip  on;
    client_max_body_size  200M;
    client_body_buffer_size 200M;

    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }

    upstream websocket_pool {
        ip_hash;
        server 127.0.0.1:22280;
    }

    server {
        listen       *:80;

        access_log /var/log/nginx/access.log;
        error_log /var/log/nginx/error.log;

        root /srv/phabricator/phabricator/webroot;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;

        location /.well-known/ {
            root /srv/letsencrypt-webroot;
        }

        location / {
            index index.php;

            if ( !-f $request_filename )
            {
                rewrite ^/(.*)$ /index.php?__path__=/$1 last;
                break;
            }
        }

        location /index.php {
            include /app/fastcgi.conf;
            fastcgi_param PATH "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin";
            fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;
        }

        location = /ws/ {
            proxy_pass http://websocket_pool;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_read_timeout 999999999;
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried the following but it does not work:

```
location /test {
     root /home/phragile/public;
}
```

Can someone show me what needs to be added in the .conf file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to use `alias` rather than `root` as you are attempting to map `/test` to `/home/phragile/public` and the latter does not end with the former. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#alias) for more. You will also need to execute PHP within that location (see your `location /index.php` block).

You have a very specific configuration that is designed to execute just one PHP file. A general solution for `/test` might look like:

```
location ^~ /test {
    alias /home/phragile/public;
    if (!-e $request_filename) { rewrite ^ /test/index.php last; }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        if (!-f $request_filename) { return 404; }

        include /app/fastcgi.conf;
        fastcgi_param PATH "/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/usr/sbin:/bin";
        fastcgi_pass 127.0.0.1:9000;

        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $request_filename;
    }
}
```

I have pasted your existing FastCGI directives (which I presume is working for you) and added the required value for `SCRIPT_FILENAME` (assuming you are using `php_fpm` or similar).

Of course, if there is no static content under `/test` you can simplify considerably.

Comment: This worked when I tried the following URI: `http://code.baqar.xgrid/test/index.php`

What would I have to change to make it work with only `http://code.baqar.xgrid/test/`

Comment: Move the "index index.php" statement into the server block so it's inherited by the new location block.